# How can I send form information from a dynamically populated div #printClass into another div #dbmsg?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, html

I am very new to php mysql ajax jquery programming and am having a problem loading addlabform's formdata from a div into a mysql database, therefore if my code is longwinded please forgive. I have php file teacher.php that has a div #printClass that was appended to with a form of checkbox values from getclass.php. I would like to take the checkbox values and pass them to a php file addlab.php that will load in another div #dbmsg with a message. I have tried using many different methods and have settled on trying to work with onclick and submit but I cannot pick up the values of the form in the first generated div #printClass. This is my html:

```
<div id="dbmsg"></div>This is 
<div id="printClass">Labid: 100Course: 11
<br>
<form name="addlabform">
<input name="classid" value="11" type="hidden">
<input onclick="submitit()" value="SubmitIt" type="submit">
<input onclick="additnow()" value="Add Labs" type="button">
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Taken</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>lastname1</td>
<td>firstname1</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="labdone" value="2191" id="2191" type="checkbox">
</td>
<td>
<i>Not Done</i>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>lastname2</td>
<td>firstname2</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="labdone" value="2042" id="2042" type="checkbox">
</td>
<td>
<i>Not Done</i>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$("#printClass").ready(additnow())</script>
<script>$("#printClass").ready(submitit())</script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addlabform").submit(function () {
    $.post("addlab.php", $("#addlabform").serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
    $("#dbmsg").append(data);
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

I have 3 functions get_check_values(), addit() and submitit(). get_check_values() is intended to get the values for the checkbox values, which does not work error console says that document.printClass is undefined. addit() works in loading the information into the div #dbmsg but I cant get the values from #printClass so until get_check_values works it is stuck.  submitit() reloads the original php file with the checked values in the $_REQUEST. I would prefer to use submitit() because it would make it unnecessary to add all the input values to the addit() xmlhttp.open line. Here are the functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

```js
function get_check_values()
{
var c_value = "";
for (var i=0; i < document.printClass.addlabform.labdone.length; i++)
   {
   if (document.printClass.addlabform.labdone[i].checked) {
    c_value = c_value + document.printClass.addlabform.labdone[i].value;
    alert(c_value);
return false;

  }
}
}

function submitit() {
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#addlabform").submit(function () {
    $.post("addlab.php", $("#addlabform").serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
        $("#dbmsg").append(data);
});
return false;
});
});
}    

function additnow() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("dbmsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
formvals = "tid=$tid";
var classid=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("printClass").value);
xmlhttp.open("GET","addlab.php?+tid=$tid&classid="+classid+formvals,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on this for days.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just using an ordinary form submit:

Your problem then becomes purely a PHP problem.

If there's some reason reloading the entire page is no good, you can use an iframe to ensure that only the form is reloaded (it'll still be the entire form, though):

```
<iframe src="addlab.php"></iframe>
```

Be sure to check `$_POST['submitbutton']` in your PHP to check which submit button was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for a response... Reloading the page will not work for me.  Do you know how to access form values using jquery if i do it that way I may be able to to access the checkbox values in the form.